# Unable to retrieve access token using MSAL for Android

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I've been trying to integrate my Android Application with Azure AD B2C using MSAL but I can't figure out how to retrieve my access token using a custom scope. I'm using [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-msal) MSAL samples as a reference.

I already granted my application the needed permissions but i still get this message:

> No access is found for scopes: https://rbxsoftb2c.onmicrosoft.com/rbx/get_access_token

Here's my Azure B2C settings, MSAL Constants and the API I'm trying to access :

[image]

MSAL Constants :

```cs
public class Constants {
  /* Azure AD b2c Configs */
  final static String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/%s/%s";
  final static String TENANT = "rbxsoftb2c.onmicrosoft.com";
  final static String CLIENT_ID = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
  final static String SCOPES = "https://rbxsoftb2c.onmicrosoft.com/rbx/get_access_token";
  final static String API_URL = "https://rbxsoft.azurewebsites.net/api/values";

  final static String SISU_POLICY = "B2C_1_SiUpIn";
  final static String EDIT_PROFILE_POLICY = "B2C_1_edit_profile";
}
```

My API :

```cs
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Values")]
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
  CosmosDatabaseConnection cdc = CosmosDatabaseConnection.Instance;

  // GET: api/Values
  [HttpGet]
  public JValue Get()
  {
    AppState appState = SessionManager.GetCookieSession(HttpContext.Session, User);
    return new JValue ( appState.User.profile.ToString() );
  }
}
```

Comment: The very first part of the scope in the error message (realbotixb2c) and your MSAL constants are different (rbxsoftb2c), is that a typo on the error message? If not and that's the actual error message, then you're passing a different value to MSAL than what you have in your constant.

Comment: Can you include your MSAL code as well as a screenshot of where you configured the scope for the web API?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My scope error message and MSAL Constants are the same. I was doing some tests and forgot to get this back to normal, sorry about that. i've edited my question fixing this issue. I do not have the reputation points to post another link, so here's my scopes configuration : https://imgur.com/a/PXhxh

Comment: Also, this is the MSAL code sample i'm using as reference for my project : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-msal

Comment: Did you also grant your client app access to the API via the "API Access" blade? Screenshot of that please.

Comment: Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/znJ8o